# SQL code SUM CASE statements

Tags: sql, sum, case

I have one table that I must count the number of orders for specific part numbers, for each customer on each of their orders.  I am getting the error

```
"Column 'ALL_INFORMATION.CUSTOMER_ID' is invalid in the select list because
 it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

I don't know what else to do.  Below is my code.  I appreciate any and all assistance.

```
WITH ALL_INFORMATION
    AS (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SO_ID, CHANGE_DATE, PART_ID, ORDER_QTY, PRODUCT_LINE FROM SOFBH),
PRODUCT_QUANTITY
AS (
    SELECT  *,
    sum(
        case when PART_ID = '3860+' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '3860+',
    sum(
        case when PART_ID = '3861' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '3861',
    sum(
        case when PART_ID = '3865' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '3865',
    sum(
        case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1055' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '1055',
    sum(
        case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1056' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '1056',
    sum(
        case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1057' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '1057',
    sum(
        case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1058' then ORDER_QTY else 0
    end) as '1058'
FROM ALL_INFORMATION)


select *
FROM ALL_INFORMATION
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, SO_ID
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do way too much in one query.  I think the approach you should take is to create some temp tables, with a master table/view that pulls all your data together and sums the values you need. Like so:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp3860 (gather, fields, here)
CREATE TABLE tmp3861 (gather, fields, here)
CREATE TABLE tmp3865 (gather, fields, here)...
```

Then do a UNION

```
SELECT * FROM tmp3860 UNION SELECT * FROM tmp3861 ...
```

and insert those into a View or another master temp table.
Then in that View or Master Temp table do your sums

Answer (score 0):

That is because your SQL statement below does not have any aggregate function (SUM, AVG, etc) used within where GROUP BY is used.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_INFORMATION
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, SO_ID
```

Yes you used SUM() function in your SQL but not within where GROUP BY is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the *summarized* value on each *row*, then use window functions:

```
PRODUCT_QUANTITY as (
 SELECT  *,
         sum(case when PART_ID = '3860+' then ORDER_QTY else 0 end) over () as '3860+',
```

You need to do this (add `over ()`) for each `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below query , I think it's what you need.

```
SELECT  CUSTOMER_ID, SO_ID,
sum(
    case when PART_ID = '3860+' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '3860+',
sum(
    case when PART_ID = '3861' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '3861',
sum(
    case when PART_ID = '3865' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '3865',
sum(
    case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1055' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '1055',
sum(
    case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1056' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '1056',
sum(
    case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1057' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '1057',
sum(
    case when PRODUCT_LINE = '1058' then ORDER_QTY else 0
end) as '1058'

FROM PRODUCT_QUANTITY GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID, SO_ID
```